# Coulomb's law with an $r^3$, not $r^2$, in the denominator

Tags: electrostatics, vectors, coulombs-law

I am reading an older physics book that my professor gave me. It is going over Coulomb's law and Gauss' theorem. However, the book gives both equations with an $r^3$, not $r^2$, in the denominator. Can somebody please explain why it is given as r^3? An image is attached for reference.

Also for equation 1-24, can somebody please explain how the middle side is equal to the right side with the del operator?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we say that in Coulomb's law the force is proportional to $\frac{1}{r^{2}}$ and not $\frac{1}{r^{3}}$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73075/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does give "Coulomb's law" with $\frac{1}{r^3}$, it gives it in its proper vectorial form
$$ \vec E \propto \frac{\vec r}{r^3}$$
which, when taking the absolute values, yields the form you are probably more familiar with
$$ E \propto \frac{1}{r^2}$$
since $\lvert \vec r \rvert = r$.

Comment: Great, thank you for the help. Also, in the figure at the bottom of the attached image, do you know what the d(**omega**) stands for?

Comment: @DevinSchneider: Differential solid angle.