# Why the $r$ is cubed in the vector notation for of Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors

I'm learning about astrodynamics on my own and I was wondering why the $r$ is cubed in the vector notation for of Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation:

$$\vec{F}_g=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{|\vec{r}|^3}\vec{r}$$

I am familiar with Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation of the form:

$$F_g=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Explained in the answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73075/50583), and almost an exact duplicate of [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194894/50583) with "Coulomb" replaced by "Newton".

Answer (score 9):

$$\vec{F}_g=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|^3} \vec{r}_{ij}=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|^3} |r_{ij}|\hat{r}_{ij}=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|^2} \hat{r}_{ij}.$$

It's just one way textbooks write it, and is exactly equivalent to the right-most expression, which is probably the most obvious way to write the gravitational force in vector notation.

Answer (score 6):

In vector notation Newtonian force of gravity is
$$
\vec F = \frac{GMm\vec r}{r^3},
$$
where $r = \sqrt{(x_1 - x'_1)^2 + (x_2 - x'_2)^2 + (x_3 - x'_3)^2}$ and the radial vector $\vec r = \vec x - \vec x'$. we can consider the unit vector $\hat r = \frac{\vec r}{r}$ We can the write the vector notation as
$$
\vec F = \frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r = F_g\hat r.
$$
which uses the scalar form of Newton's law of gravity. To write in component notation with $\hat r = (\hat r_1, \hat r_2, \hat r_3)$ we have
$$
F_i = \frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r_i = F_g\hat r_i.
$$

Comment: Instead of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$, I think you intended to write $x$, $y$, and $z$.