# Inverse Square Law and extra space dimensions

Tags: newtonian-gravity, spacetime-dimensions, gauss-law

Newton's famous Inverse Square Law says that in $n=3$ dimension of space, force is inversely proportional to the square of the distance between a source and a target.

I [understand that for higher dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law#Field_theory_interpretation), this can be generalized as thus:

$$F\propto1/r^{n-1}$$

Where $n$ is the dimension of the space.

Why is this so? Is there a rigorous derivation of this from a deep fundamental theory? Or is there a heuristic argument why this is so?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law#Field_theory_interpretation

Comment: @Marcel, that's exactly the link I want to quote, but somehow forgot. Beyond what is written in the wiki, can you elucidate more?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47193/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this more "intuitively" (idiosyncratically): the [flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux) of this force in [closed surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_surface) is equal to the quantity of source inside (is a [Gauss's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law)). This source could be a mass or a charge. The physical picture is: the pressure applied in a closed surface by the field-force is proportional to the quantity of source inside.

[image]

You can get the force-field produced by a [point source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_source) with suitable choices of surface (a sphere concentric with the source). Then for any dimension you can see that your field obey the $\frac{1}{r^{d-1}}$ because the area of this surface ([$d$-sphere, $S_2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)) grow with $r^{d-1}$ (for $d>2$).

Yes, exist a more "rigorous" (Standard) derivation. Actually we need to check first that this law imply a potential that obey the [Laplace's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation): $\nabla^2 V(x)=0$. Any point source of this force will produce a potential that is a [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) of $\nabla^2$ for suitable boundary condition ($V=0$ at $\infty$).

For three dimensions, the Green's function is $\frac{1}{r}$, this imply $\frac{1}{r^2}$ for the force. For $d>2$, the Green's function is $\frac{1}{r^{d-2}}$ and imply a force that is $\frac{1}{r^{d-1}}$. For $d=2$ is a logarithm and for $d=1$ is linear with $r$.