# Does gravity exist in higher dimensions?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions

I’m very curious to know whether gravity exists in higher dimensions. Because it follows the inverse square law it seems to me that it should be 3D only (just intuition). Is there any mathematical evidence of your answer or any experiment that can test it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse Square Law and extra space dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176811/)

Comment: It exists in higher dimensions but is not inverse square. Just solve Poisson’s equation for a point mass in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to find the Newtonian gravitational potential in any dimension.

Comment: Okay.. thanks for comments. So gravity exist in higher dimension. Is there any way to test that out ???

Comment: But also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/97/123208

Comment: If additional dimensions exist, they would be microscopic and highly curved. They are too small to be noticed at the energies achievable at, say, the LHC. Even if we eventually discover higher dimensions, it will be extremely difficult to test gravity in them except indirectly through other predictions about other forces.